# Can I solve this multi-variable limit with polar coordinates: $\lim_{ (x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{y^2\sin^2(x)}{x^4+y^4}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

$$\lim_{ (x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{y^2\sin^2(x)}{x^4+y^4}$$

I know that I could let $x=0$ and solve the limit, and then the same for $y=x$.
But I want to know if I could solve it only with polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want proceed by polar coordinates as a first step we can use

$$\frac{y^2\sin^2(x)}{x^4+y^4}=\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}\frac{y^2x^2}{x^4+y^4}$$

with $\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2} \to 1$ and then use polar coordinates for the second term.

Answer (score 2):

Using user's answer $\frac{x^2y^2}{x^4+y^4}= \frac{r^4 \sin^2a\cos^2a}{r^4(\sin^4a+\cos^4a)}= \frac{\sin^2a\cos^2a}{\sin^4a+\cos^4a}$, where angle $a$ can assume any value as $r\to 0$.  Therefore the expression has no limit as both $x,y\to 0$.

Comment: As an alternative we can also take $x^2=r\cos \theta$ and  $y^2=r\sin \theta$ in order to avoid the needing to discuss the fact that $\sin^4a+\cos^4a\ge c>0$.

Comment: @user  That is not the usual way to switch to polar coordinates.

Comment: I agree that in this case that's in both ways since we want just show that limit doesn't exist. In other cases using the second way could be convenient. Bye